# which rostopic should 3rd part controller publish to, to control a real Universal Robot?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am attempting to control a UR5 robot arm using a neural network controller.
With the minimum amount of reconfiguring, to which topic should the joint commands from the neural network be published?
The network output will be a tuple of joint movements of +/- 1 degree.
How could I test such a publication message using the command line?
This is using ROS Kinetic.
Thanks,
Dom

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315668/which-rostopic-should-3rd-part-controller-publish-to,-to-control-a-real-universal-robot?/) by [porkPy](https://answers.ros.org/users/38648/porkpy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Provided you are using the `kinetic-devel` version of `ur_modern_driver` and provided you are running your network at 125 Hz and you make sure to not violate any limits, you could make use of the `ros_control` compatibility, configure a `JointGroupPositionController`, keep track of the absolute joint angles and publish new targets to the position controller.

Alternatively: use the `JointGroupVelocityController` that's already there and publish velocities.

Another alternative could be to use something like [jog_arm](http://wiki.ros.org/jog_arm) between you and the driver. It can take care of some of the steps I wrote about above.

---

Edit:

> which rostopic should 3rd part controller publish to

just an observation: *all* controllers would be "3rd party" in this setup. I'm not sure what would make yours different from any other.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [porkPy](https://answers.ros.org/users/38648/porkpy/) on 2019-02-18**:
Hi gvdhoorn,
Thanks for your answer. I have managed to get jog_arm to start publishing to /move_group.
I have worked out (I think) how to publish actions to the /jog_arm_server node using the /jog_arm_server/joint_delta_jog_cmds topic using the /jog_msgs/JogJoints message.
.....

**Comment by [porkPy](https://answers.ros.org/users/38648/porkpy/) on 2019-02-18**:
Example:
 `$ rostopic pub /jog_arm_server/joint_delta_jog_cmds jog_msgs/JogJoint -1  '{stamp: now, frame_id: base_link}' [wrist_3_joint] [10]`
and I get output `publishing and latching message for 3.0 seconds`
However, the robot does not move.
Any ideas?
Many thanks

**Comment by [porkPy](https://answers.ros.org/users/38648/porkpy/) on 2019-02-18**:
If I echo the joint_delta_jog_cmds topic I get an output of:

header:
seq: 1
stamp:
secs: 1550500372
nsecs: 132920026
frame_id: "base_link"
joint_names: [wrist_3_joint]
deltas: [10.0]

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-18**:
I would recommend you ask the `jog_arm` author, @AndyZe. Either here on ROS Answers or in an issue on his tracker.

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2019-02-18**:
See [the Github issue](https://github.com/UTNuclearRoboticsPublic/jog_arm/issues/88)

**Comment by [porkPy](https://answers.ros.org/users/38648/porkpy/) on 2019-02-18**:
Ok, will do. Thank you for your help.